# apt-get update зависает на определённом моменте

Tags: debian, apt-get, apt

Debian 8.6 Jessie

Пробовал ставить разные источники.

Если
source.list:

```
# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie-updates main

# jessie-backports, previously on backports.debian.org
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie-backports main

deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

то apt-get update зависнет на 0%

```
root@homeserver:~# apt-get update
0% [Connecting to ftp.ru.debian.org] [Connecting to dl.google.com]
```

С http://security.debian.org/ абсолютно то же самое.

Если поставить http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/

```
root@homeserver:~# apt-get update
Get:1 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie InRelease
Get:3 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-updates/main Sources [15.7 kB]
Get:4 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [8,392 B]
Get:5 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:6 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [3,196 B]
Get:7 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex [27.8 kB]
Get:8 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [27.8 kB]
Get:9 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:10 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [27.8 kB]
Get:11 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie Release.gpg [2,373 B]
Get:12 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:13 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/main Sources [7,055 kB]
Get:14 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/contrib Sources [50.8 kB]
Get:15 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/non-free Sources [99.5 kB]
Get:16 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,790 kB]
Get:17 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/contrib amd64 Packages [50.2 kB]
Get:18 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/non-free amd64 Packages [83.6 kB]
Get:19 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/main i386 Packages [6,793 kB]
Get:20 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/contrib i386 Packages
Get:21 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/non-free i386 Packages
Get:22 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/contrib Translation-en [38.5 kB]
Get:23 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/main Translation-en [4,583 kB]
Get:24 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net jessie/non-free Translation-en [72.1 kB]
100% [Connecting to dl.google.com]
```

то зависает на этих 100%

Answer (score 1):

1. > deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/ jessie...

   вообще вы пропустили каталог (`debian`), но если ваш компьютер находится в рф, то лучше использовать наиболее производительное зеркало — от яндекса. для этого замените

   ```
   http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/
   ```

   на

   ```
   http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/
   ```
2. > Connecting to dl.google.com

   вероятно, вы привели не всю информацию. репозитории описываются не только в файле `/etc/apt/sources.list`, но и в файлах внутри каталога `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. для теста закомментируйте в этих файлах все строки (добавив символ `#` в началах строк).